# Get all data from DB and sort client side, is this optimal or ideal?

Tags: c#, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I'm making a online chat program.

Technologies: -AJAX(methodology) -PHP -C# -ASP.net -JQuery -HTML5 -MYSQL -IIS

Issue (Long):

I've implemented group chat which works fine up to now. My issue is with multi-chat. Mind you I now realize i should have done the entire thing in PHP, but only knew ASP.net and C# when i started and will end up using PHP only, as a last resort. Anyway, when a multi-chat window is made, it injects the pre-made code via jquery into a div, stores it in sessionStorage for when the page refreshes, it loads the code from sessionstorage, and all ID's are incremented by one, for each user to have a max of 6 windows open at any given time. Now i'm trying to get specific query's for each specific users request like "SELECT * WHERE user1  privateChatID = '1' AND user2 privateChatID = '1'; (not the actual query, just pseudo code)", but since i'm using AJAX to get the query, I cant really manipulate the php file since it's loaded because the main file is a .aspx page. Now for group chat I'm using an update panel which works fine, but i can't dynamically make a draggable chat window, inside the update panel, because I'd have to use an ' runat="server" ' attribute, and if i run that in the pre-scripted jquery and wanted to increment the ID (like so: 'IDName "+ i +"'), visual studio/iis gives an error, hence the reason i'm trying to use Ajax. So all the problems I've worked out so far, once i get a working version I'll probably rethink the whole structure all together. My only issue now:

Issue (short):
Would it be easier since i can't manupulate functions or variables in the php file, to just select everything from the  DB ('message table') and sort everything client side? or would that not be optimal? OR is there a way to alter query's externally for a php file that is loaded by jquery?

Comment: It all depends how much data you've got to transfer, and how complex the filtering/sorting query would be. Personally, I'd keep it all server-side as you can't guarantee someone has javascript enabled.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan most "group chat" applications are going to be pretty rubbish if you don't have javascript enabled; but I agree with doing as much server-side as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to create php files on the server that would have their own queries, and users would have their own directories on the server for those files and i guess any other files that might need to be added to them in the future if any. I'm taking a chance if the load of bandwidth is too much because a number of users will be creating files on the server, when a chat window is create, i don't even know how secure it'll be but it's working for the time being, i'll tweak security issues, after i can get everything working.